# How to reproduce a guitar sound

Tags: logic-pro, guitar

I'm trying to reproduce this sound, and particulary the guitar (but the singer too):

(at 2:09: guitar solo)

I'm working on logic pro X.
The singer is recorded, and I recorded the guitar notes using midi and realGuitar5 plugin.
The plugin sounds great, but it's not the same sound.

My original question would be:
how do you turn an acoustic guitar sound into the guitar sound from the video?

- which plugins
- which effects
- which settings

Or an alternate question would be: what's the type of guitar playing, does it have an amp, which one?

Also, is it a good approach to analyse the wave form through an EQ analyzer, and try to shape the sound that I want
into it?

Any advice would be great.

Comment: if it doesn't sound vaguely similar to start with, no amount of EQ is going to fix it. If you have the facility in the plugin... it's a nylon-stung guitar, with quite short sustain - mic is close & quite bright on what sounds like a dull original sound, old strings [but that's a guess]… Frankly, if your plugin doesn't contain a sample that at least vaguely matches, you're stuck.

Comment: Well thanks a lot, by googling nylon-stung guitar I found Gibson Chet Atkins, and on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXcXsiXzguQ , between 2:17 and 2:20 the guy turns on the tone? control, which gives exactly the sound I need. So now I have to see if there is a plugin that does that sound. Thanks.